# What are the odds of a random number generated in given range being higher than given number?

Tags: java, random

For example, given the range between 90 and 100:

```
float a = 100;
float b = 93;
float c = 106;
a *= random.nextFloat() * 0.2f + 0.9f;
//what's the chance of a > b
//what's the chance of a > c
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Asking us to do your homework for you usually doesn't go over very well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking what is the probability that `a > b` and `a > c`.

Line 4 of your code tells us that `a` will be scaled by a factor between `0.9 and 1.1`.

Assuming that `random.nextFloat()` returns an even distribution, then there is a 17/20 chance that `a > b` because this is just the probability that the random float between 90 and 120 is in the range [93, 110].

Similarly there is a 4/20 chance that `a > c`